# Paragraph to Table in Different Columns

Tags: java, python, jtable, paragraph

I want to create a program such that if I have inserted a paragraph in a text area, I want certain parts of it to be put in the table in different columns. For example the statement is:

My name is James Olson. I am 21 years old. I am a doctor. I live in Canterville, Bacon Street, London.

Then the table should automatically look like:

---

| Name |  Age  |  Profession  |  Area Name  |  Street Name  |   Area   |

---

James  | 21    | Doctor       | Canterville | Bacon Street  | London   |

---

I also want to know which language would go the best - Python or Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it is certainly possible to do so and I would personally prefer **Python** to do the Job.

I've written the code, it is not the best or the most efficient code but it will surely *do the job* but there is a catch in my code. It will only work if the **sequence and pattern** of your sentence is same. The pattern should be exactly like the one you provided in the **example**.

If you want the code to work for multiple sentences, a slight change in the code with a loop can do the work.

```
import pandas as pd

my_sent = "My name is James Olson. I am 21 years old. I am a doctor. I live in Canterville, Bacon Street, London."
my_words = my_sent.split()

my_stopwords = ['My', 'name', 'is', 'I', 'am', 'years', 'old.', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'I', 'live', 'in',]

cleaned_stopwords = []
useful_words = []

for temp in my_stopwords:
    cleaned_stopwords.append(temp.lower().strip())

for word in my_words:
    if word.lower().strip() not in cleaned_stopwords:
        useful_words.append(word.title().strip(".").strip(","))

name = useful_words[0] + " " + useful_words[1]
street = useful_words[5] + " " + useful_words[6]

useful_words.pop(0)
useful_words.pop(0)
useful_words.insert(0, name)
useful_words.pop(4)
useful_words.pop(4)
useful_words.insert(4, street)

all_columns = ["Name", "Age", "Profession", "Area Name", "Street Name", "Area"]
my_df = pd.DataFrame([useful_words], columns = all_columns)
```

Output:

```
           Name  Age  Profession   Area Name    Street Name    Area
0   James Olson   21      Doctor Canterville   Bacon Street  London
```